# How to unit test for backward and forward compatibility?

Tags: java, unit-testing, serialization, compatibility

I am working on developing an Plug-In API that uses Java serialization. The idea is similar to SmallTalk's system images. I was wondering how would to best to automate testing for whether changes I am making will break deserialization since some changes seem to be innocuous like adding a method to an interface that is implemented (as long as that is not called, otherwise it will result in a `AbstractMethodException`).

Yes, this is more for an experimental spike rather than production code so please do not suggest not using serialisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For backward compatibility of data, keep a lot of old messages in binary form, and see if you can still deserialize them with the new code.

For backward compatibility of code, you'll need some way of building your old code (e.g. one version per release) and testing that against data created from the newest version of the code. This is a slightly more challenging problem - you may want to build a small test jar on each appropriate release, and put *that* into source control at the same time to avoid having to build the same code again and again. Your tests would then try all the different jar files against the output of the new code.

To be honest, this all sounds like quite a lot of work for an experimental spike. For real work I'd just use [protocol buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com/) of course :)

Comment: The missing detail which I didn't want to explain is that I'm trying to work on a late-binding plug-in language with open-classes so that only serialise instances can get passed around instead of class files. aiming to use it for a long running ai competition for students where they can update their logic on the fly etc. It's really a fairly unique situation that I didn't want to clutter the question with since I'm hoping that the answers will generalise to more common problems.

Comment: @ArtB: It's not clear to me exactly what that means - without the class files, I fail to see how the data will be used... but leaving that aside, does my answer still help?

Comment: Yes it does. Basically I will write the basic methods and the will merely construct calls to them. Like attaching a method to a listener. I provide the method and the listener and they combine it as they see fit. Basically you can build objects that can be arranged to form programming constructs. See the Scratch language to see how it can be done.